Is there a way to turn of friendly_id or at least the history module during testing?
I have a Rails application where I added the friendly_id with the history module enabled and performance during tests plummeted. I'm talking about going from 15 minutes to 30 minutes in the absolutely best runs, and sometimes it goes into the multi-hour mark (not sure how long, it was too long for me to wait).
My tests create a lot of records (long story for another day). There's one particular query related to the history module as far as I can tell that sometimes takes as long as 1 to 2 seconds to run. I'm not 100% sure why yet, but the reality is that I don't need the friendly_id slug generation for most tests and I don't need the history tracking except for one single test.
Is it possible to temporarily turn off friendly_id slug generation? or is it possible to turn the history module off?
The relevant code is here: https://github.com/pupeno/repeater_world/blob/b83ea68f3bbd4a12c63d726983b70f125e9b6e11/app/models/repeater.rb#L105-L106 (it's all open source):
include FriendlyId
friendly_id :generate_slug, use: [:slugged, :history]


Have you tried looking at the offending query and running explain on it? You can skip slug generation by skipping the :create_slug callback or by stubbing the method.

You can't really "turn the module off". Ruby doesn't have a way of unincluding modules and even if you could remove  the modules the side of effects  the code that runs in Module#include would still remain (the callback).

You could try this:
unless Rails.env.test?
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :generate_slug, use: [:slugged, :history]
end

But I there might be side effects, for example, when you have database not null constraints on friendly_id columns or controllers or view expect that the friendly_id is always set.

One pretty obvious side effect is the loss of test accuity and parity.
